# Server Down after Centos/PHP upgrade

Tags: php, apache, centos

I need some guidance to fix my server. I have a VPS with CentOS, Linux, PHP and plesk.

Yesterday, I made an update using yum of PHP 5.1.6 to 5.3.8 and CentOS. Updated php.ini and restarted services.but something went wrong since server is returning a 500 internal server error to all sites since then.

My apache log don't show any activity when trying to load sites, the log only displays activity when server is restarted and no errors are shown.

I am able to run .php files from ssh and php -v returns version 5.3.8

Where should I be looking at ? what may be missing?

Thanks in adavance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, this is pretty broad, i'd vote to get this transfered to serverfault as this site is mostly for code problems.

My 2 cents is that this upgraded changed something in the way your files are handled such as in mod_php5 for apache. Or it might be an HTACCESS configuration error that you're getting...

Comment: Well i have discarded HTACCESS otion since i am talking about 4 sites at the same time, and didn't change anything on them.

Comment: Still, if you have HTACCESS files and your server doesn't support them anymore after the upgrade, it could be related to it. Configuration and HTACCESS support is something related to your vhost files and permission in APACHE. Upgrading php/apache can lead to those kind of problems.

Comment: By the way, thanks for mentioning this site which is new to me, but seems to be the glory.